# Security Alternative to updating to 3.6.4

Tags: joomla-3.x, security, update

I cannot update to Joomla version 3.6.4 because core files have been changed. I am stuck at 3.4.6

I still want to protect against the vulnerabilities mentioned in https://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5678-joomla-3-6-4-released.html

Are there alternatives to manually going through and merging the core files between my version and the fixed version?

We do have security plugins like RSFirewall installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GRR stop modifying core files!

Apart from some basic XML files being updated to cater for the version, only 3 actual core PHP files were updated to fix the security exploit.

- `administrator\components\com_users\models\user.php`
- `components\com_users\controller\user.php`
- `libraries\fof\encrypt\aes.php`

I assume, well....I hope, you haven't started modifying these so the update should be fine.

Word of advice, if you need to change the way Joomla behaves, create a system plugin. That's what they're there for!

Comment: It wasn't me - I am picking up from someone else who did the site :/ 

Thanks for this help!